# If a polynomial takes integer values at every integer, does it have integer coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $f \in \mathbf R[x]$  and for every $k \in \mathbf Z$, $f(k)\in \mathbf Z$. Does this imply that $f \in \mathbf Z[x]$?

I tried to find a counter example, but my intuition tells me it's true and I don't know how to prove the statement either.

Answer (score 11):

There are those famous exercises for undergraduates like

- Show that $n^2+n$ is always even,
- Show that $n^3-n$ is always divisible by $6$.

They give rise to a lot of polynomials, which take only integer values at integers, but do not have integer coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

It follows from [Newton's interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series) that the subset of $\mathbb Q[x]$ of polynomials that take integer values at integers is the $\mathbb Z$-module generated by the binomial polynomials.

Comment: See also [Integer-valued polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Binomial coefficients...